# How to find last 24 hours data from pandas data frame

Tags: python, datetime

I have a data in which we have two columns, one is description and another is publishedAt. I applied sort function on publishedAt column and get the output of descending order of date. Here is the sample of my data frame:

```
        description publishedAt
13  Bitcoin price has failed to secure momentum in...   2018-05-06T15:22:22Z
16  Brian Kelly, a long-time contributor to CNBC’s...   2018-05-05T15:56:48Z
2   The bitcoin price is less than $100 away from ...   2018-05-05T13:14:45Z
12  Mati Greenspan, a senior analyst at eToro and ...   2018-05-04T16:05:37Z
52  A Singaporean startup developing ‘smart bankno...   2018-05-04T14:02:30Z
75  Cryptocurrencies are set to make a comeback on...   2018-05-03T08:10:19Z
76  The bitcoin price is hovering near its best le...   2018-04-30T16:26:57Z
74  In today’s climate of ICOs with 100 billion to...   2018-04-30T12:03:31Z
27  Investment guru Warren Buffet remains unsold o...   2018-04-29T17:22:19Z
22  The bitcoin price has increased by around $400...   2018-04-28T12:28:35Z
68  Bitcoin futures volume reached an all-time hig...   2018-04-27T16:32:44Z
14  Biotech-company-turned-cryptocurrency-investme...   2018-04-27T14:25:15Z
67  The bitcoin price has rebounded to $9,200 afte...   2018-04-27T06:24:42Z
```

Now i want to description of last 3 hours, 6 hours, 12 hours and 24 hours.
How can i find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As a simple solution within Pandas, you can use the [`DataFrame.last(offset)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html) function. Be sure to set the PublishedAt column as the dataframe DateTimeIndex.  A similar function to get rows a the start of a dataframe is the [`DataFrame.first(offset)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html) function.

Here is an example using the provided offsets:

```
df.last('24h')
df.last('12h')
df.last('6h')
df.last('3h')
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the dataframe is called `df`

```
import datetime as dt
df[df['publishedAt']>=(dt.datetime.now()-dt.timedelta(hours=3))]['description'] #hours = 6,12, 24
```

if you need the intervals exclusive, thus the description withing the last 6 hours but not the ones within 3 hours, you'll need to use array-like logical operators from numpy like `numpy.logicaland(arr1, arr2)` in the first breaket.

Comment: how we can do the same for minutes

Comment: the datetime:timedelta -function uses keywords for its parameteres `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, `days` etc...